# Reset value in ASP.NET for Image data type in SQL Server

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server

In ASP.NET I wish to empty/clear/reset the contents on an `Image` data type in SQL Server.
I will then later check to see if this column is empty/null - if not, I will output the image.

Can you tell me the necessary C#? Here is what I have presently...

```
newsItem.Image1 = null;
dataContext.SubmitChanges();
```

The above actually gives me "0x" when I look through SQL Server Management Studio, so its not actually empty.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is Nullable in DB then use

```
newsItem.Image1= null;
```

else

```
newsItem.Image1= new Binary( new byte[0] );
```

Comment: An idea which Directive I need to Use for Binary?

Comment: add reference to System.Data.Linq

Comment: I still get in the column 0x when setting to new Binary(new byte[0]). How do I make this column nullable in the BD?

Answer (score 0):

Couple things come to mind:

In your database, is Image nullable?

You may have to remove and recreate the entire row of that table to ensure that the field is removed.